# Push Notification on a Button Tap

Tags: c#, push-notification, uwp, iot

I am working on Universal Windows Platform(IOT-UWP). I want to fire a push notification at a button tap event. Is there any way of doing it? or is it even possible? Also, if my IoT device receives a push notification, is there any way I can perform some actions as soon as a notification arrives assuming the IoT UWP application is running and the user has can't tap on the notification. Can I handle such an event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a push notification is under the control of the app (or more typically, its related web service) and you don't need any special platform APIs for doing that; you just need to send the correct payload to the Microsoft Push Notification server, using the ChannelURI you got when registering the client. You can read more about it on MSDN: [Windows Push Notification Services (WNS) overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187203.aspx).

Your client code can handle incoming "raw" push notifications. The raw notifications don't show any UI by default, but you can have your background task show the UI if you also want to notify the user. You can read more about it on MSDN: [Raw notification overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187200.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the app's cloud service is Azure so does it mean that I'll connect my phone app to my REST API hosted in azure and the REST API would be firing up the notifications using notification hubs?

Comment: Presumably there is some event in the real-world that would trigger the notification. What is that event, and where does it come from?

Comment: I found out the solution, thankful for your links. For others with same querry refer the direct link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ709907(v=win.10).aspx